# Simplify $\sin (90 - \theta)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Title.

I have no idea what to do. Is their an identity I have to remember? What am I supposed to do to the equation? Do I have to solve for something first, what does it mean by simplify?

Comment: ever heard of $sin(A-B)$ equality, where A can be 90 and B is $\theta$?

Comment: Hint: Draw both $\sin(\theta)$ and $\sin(90-\theta)$ and see how you can relate them.

Comment: @Sid I am not familiar with that or how to utilize it..

Comment: sketch a right triangle and write the sin and cos ratios for both acute angles

Comment: Hint: Prove that $\sin(90^\circ - \theta) = \cos(\theta)$ by drawing out a right-angled triangle with hypotenus of length $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sin(90-\theta)=\cos(\theta)$ because:
$\sin(\alpha-\beta)=\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta)-\cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta)$

Comment: How is sin(a-b) equal to what you elaborated upon? wouldn't it be sin a * sin - b ? Were did cos come from??

Comment: @sasha: it's an usual trigonometric formula. See for example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_trigonometric_identities

Comment: @sasha this is not literal multiplication, its called function notation, I hope you know that by now

Answer (score 2):

$\theta$ and $90°-\theta$ are called complementary angles. (Similarly, $\theta$ and $180°-\theta$ are called supplementary angles.)
Among the very first trigonometric identities that you must know by heart, you find

Opposite:
$$\sin(-\theta)=-\sin\theta\text{, }\cos(-\theta)=\cos\theta.$$

Complementary:
$$\sin(90°-\theta)=\cos\theta\text{, }\cos(90°-\theta)=\sin\theta.$$
Supplementary:
$$\sin(180°-\theta)=\sin\theta\text{, }\cos(180°-\theta)=-\cos\theta.$$

[image]

Comment: As an exercise, you can find by yourself the formulas for anticomplementary angles ($\theta, 90°+\theta$) and antisupplementary ones ($\theta, 180°+\theta$).

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin(\alpha-\beta)=\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta)-\cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta)$

with 
$\alpha = 90$ 
you get
$\sin(90) = 1$ and $\cos(90) = 0$

So it becomes
$1*\cos(\theta) - 0*\sin(\theta) = \cos(\theta)$